# Linker error for different declarations of default constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have been playing around with default constructors and noticed a weird behavior (from my point of view).

When I declare `A() = default`, I get no linker error.

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  A() = default;
};

A a; // no linker error
```

However, when I declare `A();` I get it.

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  A();
};

A a; // linker error - undefined reference to `A::A()`
```

**Questions**:

1. What's the difference between the two?
2. And if `A();` produces a linker error, why is it supported in the first place? Any practical applications?

**UPDATE (Follow-up Question)**

For `A();` why can't it be implicitly defined by the compiler if no definition is specified by the user?

Comment: `A();` only declares that the constructor exists, but it doesn't define it. Since the linker can't find the definition you get a `undefined reference` error.

Comment: @super and in the first case `=default` defines the ctor.

Comment: @code - There is a third option, where you don't mention `A()` at all in the declaration. Then the compiler will attempt to create the equivalent of `A() = default;` if such a constructor is needed. That's the implicit option.

Comment: @BoPersson, true. the question is if the compiler can implicitly define a constructor when a class haven't explicitly defined one, why can't the compiler assume `A();` would be `A() = default` if the user haven't explicitly defined it? @Vlad already had answered. I'm curious about your thoughts.

Comment: @code - It is like Vlad says, according to the language rules `A();` is "user defined", and so the user has to define it. The reason is that this is what was decided, so "because".

Comment: thanks @BoPersson! appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of writing

```
A();
```

is to declare to the compiler that a definition of what A() should actually do will be given somewhere else (by you!), and if it is given in another compilation unit (cpp-file) the linker is responsible for finding this definition.

```
A() = default;
```

is a way of declaring to the compiler that it should create a definition of what should be done on construction of an A, automatically, subject to the rules of the language. So because the definition is already given, the linker won't complain about not finding it.

Why is it supported to declare without defining A() in the first place? Because you want to be able to compile different cpp-files independently. Otherwise you would always have to compile all your code, even if 99% of it hasn't changed.

The construction of an A will most likely be defined in "A.cpp". If you have completed the design of your struct A then ideally "A.cpp" will be compiled once and never again. If you construct an A in a different class/struct/compilation unit "B.cpp" then the compiler can trust in the existence of a definition for A() while compiling "B.cpp", without knowing what the definition actually looks like.

**As to the follow-up question**, "why it can't be defined implicitly": this is probably a misunderstanding about why errors occur. Compiler/linker errors do not occur to punish you. They don't mean that the compiler is pretending not to be able to do something although it can. Errors occur in order to remind you that you are breaking your own promises and any attempt by the compiler or the linker to repair that, might be possible, but is most likely not going to work as you want it to, because there are signs that you have lost track of your own requirements.

That being said, A() could be defined implicitely. **But if you write "A();" you are explicitely telling the compiler not to do it implicitly, and telling the linker to remind you, if you should ever forget to define it.** This doesn't only apply to constructors but to every kind of method, most of which have no natural sense of what it means to define them implicitely. What is the default definition of "A.makeMoney"? It is non-trivial and by writing A.makeMoney(); you are telling the compiler: "trust me, I'm gonna define somewhere how it's gonna be done".

Comment: if the user haven't defined it, is there any part of the standard that states why it can't be implicitly defined?

Comment: ... the standard won't answer "why" questions. It assumes that what's useful turns out in context. Likewise the legislation of Great Britain won't tell you why steering wheels have to be on the right-hand side of the car.

Comment: thanks Oliver. for your statement `explicitely telling the compiler not to do it implicitly, and to remind you, if you should ever forget to define it.`, can you share a reference?

Comment: @codekaizer: You can read about the meaning of declarations in Stroustrup's classic book. But don't ask me on what page exactly. But then again, recommending this book for that single question would be overkill. You can read it almost everywhere on the web. Just google for somehting like "c++ declaration definition default constructor linker"

Comment: thank you! appreciate it. maybe you need a bookmark to explicitly define what page it is. :)

Answer (score 5):

In the first case the compiler itself defines the constructor.
Take into account that in the first case the constructor declaration is at the same its definition.

In the second case as the constructor is a user-defined constructor then it is the user who must to define the constructor. In the second case there is only a declaration of the constructor.

Take into account that you can declare a constructor and then define it using the specifier `default`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A();
};

A::A() = default;

int main() 
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the user haven't defined it, is there any part of the standard that states why it can't be implicitly defined?

Comment: @codekaizer If the constructor is called then it must be defined.

Comment: true. forgive my curiosity but why doesn't the compiler just fall-back to `A() = default` if the user haven't defined `A();`?

Comment: @codekaizer Because a program can consists from several compilation uinits. So the compiler can not know whether it is a mistake of the user.

Answer (score 2):

(15.1 Constructors)

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for
>   which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a
>   default argument (including the case of a constructor with no
>   parameters). **If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a
>   non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (11.4).** An implicitly-declared default constructor is an
>   inline public member of its class.

Purpose of

```
A() = default;
```

is to tell compiler to create default constructor, as if no constructor  was defined by user. Consider this case

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  A(int v): a(v) {}
};

A a; // compiler error, no default constructor
```

If ANY constructor was declared by user, default one will be gone.

By adding `A() = default;` to that declaration you would allow class A to be constructed that way. It is *explicitly-defaulted* (11.4.2)

> A function definition whose function-body is of the form = default ;
>   is called an explicitly-defaulted definition. A function that is
>   explicitly defaulted shall
>
> (1.1) — be a special member function,
>
> (1.2) — have the same declared function type (except for possibly
>   differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy
>   constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be
>   “reference to non-const T”, where T is the name of the member
>   function’s class) as if it had been implicitly declared, and
>
> (1.3) — not have default arguments.

Methods follow same linking rules as any functions with external linking. If you declare any method in class body and  your code refers to that method (in case of constructor - by creating object of this class), you have to  define it in any compilation module of same program, otherwise program will be ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more info for `A::A();`

Referring to [class.ctor/1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#1.2):

> The class-name shall not be a typedef-name. In a constructor
>   declaration, each decl-specifier in the optional decl-specifier-seq
>   shall be friend, inline, explicit, or constexpr.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>    S();      // declares the constructor
> };
>
> S::S() { }   // defines the constructor
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Thus, `A();` is just a declaration and not a definition causing:

```
undefined reference to `A::A()'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
```

Here, you're saying that the constructor should be implemented automagically, i.e. any class members that have a default constructor will be initialized with it, and any class members that don't have a default constructor will be left uninitialized.

---

```
struct A
{
  A();
```

Here, you're saying that you will implement a default constructor.  So you have to implement it.  E.g.

```
A::A()
: a(42)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is additional information, and is supplemental to the answer provided by others.

There is a difference w.r.t. the context of special member functions, when we use the terms such as *defaulted*, *undeclared* and *deleted*.

When a special member function is:

- **undeclared** : It does not participate in overload resolution. To use this functionality, just don't declare the special member function.
- **deleted** : It participates in overload resolution. It prevents compilation, if used anywhere. To use this functionality, the keyword is `delete`
- **defaulted** : It participates in overload resolution. The default, compiler generated code is provided as the definition. To use this functionality, the keyword is `default`

There is an interesting talk by Howard Hinnat on the same, where he explains when the special member functions are defaulted/deleted/undeclared - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk